# Multimodule gradle project I get Error: Not Found (Spring with module dependency)

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, multi-module

When studying and implementing a multimodule project with Java and Gradle, I am having the following error when making a request:

`Postman`

```
{
     "status": 404,
     "error": "Not Found",
     "message": "No message available",
     "path": "/tasks/hello"
}
```

**When running the command "./gradlew :task-service:bootRun" the project seems to start normally "Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path''. But when making requests, I get "not found". I can't say where the error is, but I realize that the import of the "domain" module is not correct or I don't know how to configure it. Can you help me?**

The project and its modules - `group 'com.nyuro'`

```
nyuro-backend (root-project)
 *domain
 *task-service
```

The "domain" module contains entities, such as the Task class. Services will be Spring Boot app with @Controller, @Service, @Repository. In this example "task-service".

Here are the main snippets of settings. I hope that's enough to point me out some configuration error. Or here is the code on github: [Project Link Here](https://github.com/rafnakb/nyuro-backend)

`settings.gradle(nyuro-backend)`

```
rootProject.name = 'nyuro-backend'
include 'domain'
include 'task-service'
```

`build.gradle(nyuro-backend)`

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
}

group 'com.nyuro'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

`build.gradle(:domain)`

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
}

group 'com.nyuro'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
    implementation 'jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:3.1.0'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

`build.gradle(:task-service)`

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'com.nyuro'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    runtimeOnly 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation project(':domain')
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

`TaskServiceApplication.java`

```
@EntityScan({"com.nyuro.domain"})
@EnableJpaRepositories({"com.nyuro.domain"})
@ComponentScan({"com.nyuro.domain"})
@SpringBootApplication
public class TaskServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TaskServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

There seems to be a problem importing the domain.models.Task module. I also did several tests on @EntityScan, @EnableJpaRepositories, @ComponentScan imports. No satisfactory result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 404 Not Found error comes solely from your Controller not being picked up because of custom ComponentScan annotation on SpringBootApplication but let me raise a few more points:

1. You should not commit `.gradle`, `.idea`, `build`, etc. directories to Git. Create a `.gitignore` file to ignore them - you have one but its inside `task-service`, you should have one in root directory ideally (but you can have more specific to some particular sub-projects)
2. You have 2 gradle wrappers (in root and task-service) - the one in task-service should be removed
3. I don’t think you need `task-service/settings.gradle` file as well. I realise you probably started with a single-module project and turned it into a multi-module one.
4. You are making `ComponentScan` and `EntityScan` on `com.nyuro.domain` but you have no classes in this package (domain classes are in `module` package), most importantly `@SpringBootApplication` already does component scan on the package it is located in. You should remove `@ComponentScan(“com.nyuro.domain”)` as it prevents you Controller which is not under that package from being picked up by Spring (SpringBootApplication is in `com.nyuro.taskservice` and controller in `com.nyuro.taskservice.controllers` so the default component scan will pick it up as its a sub-package). If you want to scan additional packages you will have to add `task-service` package as well - `@ComponentScan({"com.nyuro.domain", "com.nyuro.taskservice"})`.
5. You database setup is not working for me, I had to remove it to make this app start

Comment: thank you for your suggestions. They will review all items cited in their response. The mutlimodulo project is a new study for me. I will soon post the completion of the settings here for others who have the same question.